# How to perform a query that shows me data from the current month and the previous month in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I receive information to my SQL Server table by uploading an Excel file on the web.

I have to create a stored procedure where I have to select a line (part of my table), the name of the month and the year that I want to get that information. So there are three parameters.

I show an example of the query I'm doing.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_NIVELES(
@NIVEL VARCHAR(15),
@MES VARCHAR(12),
@AÑO INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @NIVEL = 'LINEA MC'
        BEGIN
            SELECT LINEAMC, SUM(MONTODEBITO) AS DEBITO, SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS CREDITO, SUM(MONTODEBITO) - SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS TOTAL 
            FROM PRUEBAOPEX p 
            WHERE MES = @MES
            AND AÑO = @AÑO
        GROUP BY LINEAMC
    END
        
    ELSE
        RAISERROR('Linea Incorrecta', 16, 1)
END
```

My problem is that the "MES" column is of type varchar and my "AÑO" column is of type int.
I need to get the information from the previous month (in addition to the month I select as a parameter), is there a way to get the previous month when the "MONTH" field is of type varchar? Or is there a way to include the date data type for this query (would be more efficient I think)? If it existed, what would it be like?

Comment: What defines a "previous" value for a `varchar`? What is the value "before" a `varchar` value like `'Sardines'`?

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: I define the MES column of my table as varchar because within the Excel file to which I transfer the information, that column shows the name of the month as such.

Comment: A month isn't enough to work out what is previous, @Mendel. *Dates* also have a day and year component, and for months you would minimally need the year to know if one month was before or after another. December, for example, is *after* Janurary within the same calendar year, but December 2022 is *before* January 2023, not after. You need to store `date` values, not `varchar` values; fix your design, *that* is the solution.

Comment: You could use a lookup table to match months to integers if you have to, but larnu's recommendation is the appropriate respose. You have serious issues with your solution that will cause problems scaling later. There is pretty much NEVER a valid reason to store a date as its parts. Store it as a date. If you need to pass in your parameters in date parts that is fine, but always store a date as a date rather than its parts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to CONVERT to a real date and do your math on that. Hopefully your server localized to your language, try this and see if it recognizes you rmonth names

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_NIVELES(
@NIVEL VARCHAR(15),
@MES VARCHAR(12),
@AÑO INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @NIVEL = 'LINEA MC'
        BEGIN
          with cteDates as (
             SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(@MES, ' 1, ', CONVERT(char(5), @Ano)))) as TooLate
             , DATEADD(month, -1, CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(@MES, ' 1, ', CONVERT(char(5), @Ano)))) as Earliest
           )
          SELECT LINEAMC, SUM(MONTODEBITO) AS DEBITO, SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS CREDITO, SUM(MONTODEBITO) - SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS TOTAL 
          FROM PRUEBAOPEX as p CROSS JOIN cteDates as D
          WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(@MES, ' 1, ', CONVERT(char(5), @Ano))) < TooLate
              AND CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(@MES, ' 1, ', CONVERT(char(5), @Ano))) >= Earliest

        GROUP BY LINEAMC
    END
        
    ELSE
        RAISERROR('Linea Incorrecta', 16, 1)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume @MES will contain the name of the month in Spanish. You could try and get the month number out of its name but that can be problematic depending on the localization of your database. In your case I would do something like the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_NIVELES(
@NIVEL VARCHAR(15),
@MES VARCHAR(12),
@AÑO INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MesAnterior NVARCHAR(12), @AñoMesAnterior INT;
    SET @MesAnterior =  CASE @MES    
                            WHEN 'Enero' THEN 'Diciembre'
                            WHEN 'Febrero' THEN 'Enero'
                            WHEN 'Marzo' THEN 'Febrero'
                            WHEN 'Abril' THEN 'Marzo'
                            WHEN 'Mayo' THEN 'Abril'
                            WHEN 'Junio' THEN 'Mayo'
                            WHEN 'Julio' THEN 'Junio'
                            WHEN 'Agosto' THEN 'Julio'
                            WHEN 'Septiembre' THEN 'Agosto'
                            WHEN 'Octubre' THEN 'Septiembre'
                            WHEN 'Noviembre' THEN 'Octubre'
                            WHEN 'Diciembre' THEN 'Noviembre'
                        END;
    SET @AñoMesAnterior = CASE @MES WHEN 'Enero' THEN @AÑO - 1 ELSE @AÑO END; 

    IF @NIVEL = 'LINEA MC'
        BEGIN
            SELECT LINEAMC, SUM(MONTODEBITO) AS DEBITO, SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS CREDITO, SUM(MONTODEBITO) - SUM(MONTOCREDITO) AS TOTAL 
            FROM PRUEBAOPEX p 
            WHERE (MES = @MES AND AÑO = @AÑO) OR (MES = @MesAnterior AND AÑO = @AñoMesAnterior)            
        GROUP BY LINEAMC
    END
    
    ELSE
        RAISERROR('Linea Incorrecta', 16, 1)
END
```

Of course, this would work if the names of the months are "known" and uniform across your table.

Hope it helps